# График из 1000000 точек

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

Необходимо построить line график на странице, который содержит в себе примерно миллион (+- 1000) точек. Лучший вариант - изображать только часть точек и при приближении брать более детально какую-то часть. Матлаб это делает с лёгкостью. Есть ли возможность сделать такое и на странице, используя js или любой другой язык.

Comment: ну дак так и реализуйте, в чем заговздка?

Comment: https://github.com/curran/data-reduction